# Why does this code give an "undefined" error getting a scalar value from the database using jquery.ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

hiiii , i am begginer in jquery.ajax ,
i try to get a scalar value from DB but it alert undefined , i don't know why .
below is HTML page

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/getdep",
                data: '{x:1}',
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json charset-utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and below code.cs

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [webmethod]
    public string getdep(int x)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select depname from dep where depid="+x, connection);
            connection.Open();
            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're attempting to receive an item via AJAX from a server you would need to set `type` to `"GET"` not `"POST"`

Comment: but i need to send a parameter to go through the web service method [ x ]